# Issue with LogSubscribe

Tags: websocket, subscription

My end goal is to get all new tokens being created, currently am doing this by using logSubscribe to the Token Program (TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA) and filtering transactions.

The problem is only the WebSocket only receives 40-50% of incoming transactions. I am using multiple high end RPCs with RPCPool & QuickNode.

Is there something I can do to fix this issue or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Also, not looking to use any external APIs to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the commitment from "finalized" to "confirmed" fixed this issue. It's now catching all transactions.